# Windows Phone 8.1 app shows exception "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

In first page I tap an image to view in large. This tapping event takes me to another second page. In this second page I zoom in or out the image. After that I press back key and come back to the first page. Then it throws this error message.

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
System.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodPack(IntPtr objectPtr, String methodName, Object[] rawData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_TransformToVisual(UIElement element, UIElement visual)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.TransformToVisual(UIElement visual)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.GetInverseTransform(Boolean includeOffset, UIElement target)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.OnPinchCompleted(ManipulationDeltaEventArgs lastPinchInfo, Boolean gestureCompleted)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureListener.OnManipulationDelta(Object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

I am trying to find out the reason and solution of this problem but failed. I am looking for fruitfull answers to this question.

Comment: Are you using a LongListSelector? Can be related to it.

Comment: In first page I have used LongListSelector

Comment: LongListSelector can cause this Exception if `LayoutMode` is Grid and the `GridCellSize` is not specified. Or you can create a new class inheriting from `LongListSelector`, override the `MeasureOverride` method, and check if the code inside it is causing the exception.

Comment: If you move from first page to second page and selection is enabled in the longlistselector then on navigating back this issue comes. Can you try to closes multiple selection before navigating to new page. Hope this helps